# css - extending navbar prevents clicking on inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar that extends when you click on it, but when I try to interact with inputs and buttons, I am not able to click on them.  I know this a problem with the navbar because I tried removing it and website worked perfectly fine.  I think there is a problem with how I am extending it because if you go to the addNote page the last input box works fine, but only half of it is clickable.

https://postnote.herokuapp.com/addNote

This is the css for the menu:

```
.menu{
  background: red;
  width:100%;
  min-height:10vh;
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom: 0.4px solid #C0C5CD;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-item{
  font-size:0em;
  color:black;
  margin-top: 1.2vh;
  display:block;
  opacity:0;
  height: 0px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 0.7px solid #C0C5CD;
  background:red;
  display: none;
}
.menu-item-extend{
  opacity:1;
  height: 5.5vh;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  display: block;
}
.noStyle{
  border: none;
}
```

and this is the html for the menu (in react v4):

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor"
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { SubjectRoutes } from "../subjectRoutes/subjectRoutes";
import "../../../client/stylesheets/authentication.css"

class Menu extends React.Component{
  extendMenu(){
    let menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
    for(let i = 0; i <= menuItems.length; i++ ){
      menuItems[i].classList.toggle("menu-item-extend") 
    }
    console.log(menuItems)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="center center-v-outer">
        <div className="menu center-v-inner" ref="menu" onClick={this.extendMenu.bind(this)}>
          <h1 className="menu-header">PostNote</h1>
          <p className="menu-item"><Link to="/">Home</Link></p>
          <p className="menu-item"><Link to="/searchNotes">Notes</Link></p>
          <p className="menu-item"><Link to="/addNote">Add a Note</Link></p>
          <p className="menu-item noStyle"><Link to={`/users/${Meteor.userId()}`} >My Profile</Link></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(Menu)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapper div.center.center-v-outer is covering up the form due to the 'height: 50vh' on .center-v-outer. If you remove this, everything should work fine.

Additionally, you probably ought to move the menu out of the form ;)